# swipe distance in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Through swipe gesture, is it possible to calculate the distance of swipe (up, down, left, right)?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)distanceBetweenTwoPoints:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint

{
float x = toPoint.x - fromPoint.x;
float y = toPoint.y - fromPoint.y;
return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Hope its help you, just pass starting and endpoint to this method ....

Answer (score 0):

I've used an approach similar to this [article](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-gestures-in-iphone-application/) to recognise swipe gestures of a certain number of pixels, but if you're using a base SDK of at least 4 try using [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which can make it much easier; see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk).

Comment: have a play around with this example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Listings/Classes_GestureRecognizerViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460-Classes_GestureRecognizerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4 - looks like you can use the view?

Comment: I do this code two day ago , its tell in which side you swipe and me just try to show grid style view for images