# How can I detect a swipe gesture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Swipe Gesture in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk)

How can I detect a swipe gesture within the interface of my iPhone application?

Comment: i am really sorry if i made mistake but i am new bee in developing. i am trying to obey asking rules and thanks for your king suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a `UIView`.
2. Create a a subclass of a `UIGestureRecognizer` (sounds like you'd like to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`).
3. Use the `UIView` instance method
   `addGestureRecognizer:` to attach your UIGestureRecognizer to the `UIView` instance.

Seriously though... you should be reading documentation and books, or watching the Apple development videos as opposed to posting on here...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Being new to the iOS SDK, Apple Developer Documents will be one of your best friends, 2nd to Google anyway.