# slide show with UIGestureRecognizer and with tap action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am noob and new in development iphone application so i want to create  a slide show(ios 5 with storyboard) ( banner with 5 or 6 image and every image the user can clicked on him and go to link in itunes for the app it's like a banner but no only one it's multiple )

i want the user can swipe between images and can click in every one and go to specific link so if on people have a tutorial or documentation or sample code for how to do this it's will be very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use UIScrollView with paging, so you'll have to deal with only one UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: thanks :) i do that with uiscrollview and paging but now i want to annimate that automatic how can do this

Comment: `[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(horizontal, vertical) animated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

you can understand UIGestureRecognizers by some examples like these:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

[How to detect Swipe Gesture in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk)

http://iosdevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Facebook app's Three 20-framework for inspiration:

http://joehewitt.com/2009/03/23/the-three20-project

There is a fully functional slideshow-framework in there that you can look at and get some idea as to how you can make it on your own.

The `TTPhotoViewController` is the class you are looking for:

https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPhotoViewController.h