# iOS - Show the animation/effect in runtime based on the guesture

Tags: ios, ios5

When we perform a gesture(pan, rotate, swipe...etc), usually we navigate page, scrolling, etc. The back end recognize the gestures, that's all. What I am searching is more on UI. How can I make the screen to provide visual feedback of the gesture I have just performed?
In other words, when user's finger is on the screen, example when

Swiping - one line displays on the screen, tab - one dot displays on the screen, rotate - two curve of lines display on the screen

Let me know if my question is not cleared enough.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite a big ask. There are lots of different elements to it.

Firstly you'll need to detect gestures: [How to detect Swipe Gesture in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk)

You can find some code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460) on recognizing simple gestures.

Once you can recognize gestures, you can change the `UIImage` contained in a `UIImageView` programmatically like this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_pic.png"];
[myImageView setImage:myImage];
```

You can read more about `UIImageView` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to recognize the gestures. Your solution is to provide the gesture visual feedback using picture/image. What I am asking is like a painting. When your finger is on the screen, let say swipe, a swipe line will appear and gone after you done with the gesture.

Comment: It is like the app Fruit Ninja. When you swipe, you can see there is a visual feedback from your swipe.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't explicitly say that. You just asked for a dot or a slash on the screen. You'd do it the same way but you'd detect where the touch occurred. Then you'd programmatically place the image there.