# How to implement swipe to delete with quickdialog

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swipe, quickdialog

I am using quickdialog for a form and
I am trying to implement swipe to delete and have no idea how I would do that.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can swipe to delete elements in a section by using QSortingSection in place of QSection and setting canDeleteRows to YES.

```
QSortingSection *foosection = [[QSortingSection alloc] init];
foosection.canDeleteRows = YES;
```

Proceed to add elements as usual and you should be able to swipe each element to have a "delete" button appear. Upon hitting the delete button, the item automatically disappears from the section.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I think a combination of: [How to detect Swipe Gesture in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk)

And, probably the bit you are really worried about, how to [Add/remove new QElement to the section](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/issues/258#issuecomment-8179931) (from a github issue).

The latter suggests that the way to remove elements, in this example `extraRepayAmount`, from a section is this:

```
[self.extraRepaySection.elements removeObject:self.extraRepayAmount];
[self.quickDialogTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```