# How Change the Quotes By gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am creating application that having Quotes in Property list and it is display in UIText when i press next button another quotes comes in textview but now i want to add gesture to it when user swipe left or right accordance to that action quotes would be come . I am new to iphone . I Have done it in android using viewpagger. Would any  body have idea about this how can i make it.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow your question 100%. Does the accepted answer to this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279699/how-to-detect-swipe-gesture-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using UISwipeGestureRecognizer.
Make sure your textView is not editable.

Code as below :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe)];
[leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[_textView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipe)];
[rightSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[_textView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

- (void) leftSwipe
{
    NSLog(@"leftSwipe");
}

- (void) rightSwipe
{
    NSLog(@"rightSwipe");
}
```

Now show your quotes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To give animation to your quotes :

First of all import QuartzCore framework to you project.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now modify swipe methods as below :

```
- (void) leftSwipe
{
NSLog(@"leftSwipe");

[self curlAnimationFromLeft];
}

- (void) rightSwipe
{
NSLog(@"rightSwipe");

[self curlAnimationFromRight];
}


- (void) curlAnimationFromLeft
{
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
animation.type = @"pageCurl";
animation.subtype = @"fromRight";
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[_textView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
}

-(void)curlAnimationFromRight
{
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
animation.subtype = @"fromRight";
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.startProgress = 0.35;
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[_textView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageUnCurlAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: Prashant,i am getting error near around animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut , It says implicit conversion NSinteger.

Comment: have you added framework?

Comment: yes i have added <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> is the file that you might have imported in .m file. but have added framework for it?

Comment: Yes i have added the framework even though there is an error i think i am using ARC (Automatic Retain count) is there is any problem with that . i have removed that line error is gone now so what is befit to add that function

Comment: i found the solution instead of the function i have added this because it ARC version [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];